# Join two existing two queries using joins

Tags: mysql

I am bit confused by joining two queries which involves three tables.

First Query involves joining table1 and table2.
Secound Query involves joining table1 and table3.

By using join operation, i need to fetch the results from table1 and table2.

I want a single query by joining query1 and query2.

Query 1) This query is already existed.

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.country 
from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where t1.id =t2.id a  
and t1.stats_code in ('100','200');
```

Query 2)

```
select t1.id 
from table1 t1, table3 t3 
where t1.id = t3.id 
and t3.code in ('300')
```

My joint query should fetech 3 record by joining query1 and query2 i.e with ids with 100, 200, 300.

Please help

Comment: You should be able to write it... in your first query add "and t1.id in (your second query)"      OR use JOIN agan

Comment: You might like to use the JOIN syntax, for more accuracy and to be down with the cool kids

Comment: I don't understand. You want all 3 rows to be a result? Or you want to base your first query on the result of the second, so your t1.stats_code include the result from your second query?

Comment: @Scratte yes absolutely i want result from the second query too

Comment: It would be better if your were more clear about what your result should be. "joining" in SQL does not mean both results from the first and the second query. Also, in your respons to me you were not absolutely clear that you meant yes to my first question, but **no to my second question**. But that's how I understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JOIN you would do it like this

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.country 
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.stats_code in ('100','200');
OR t3.code = '300'
```

Comment: I think perhaps you meant `OR`?

Comment: @Scratte Now I understand why you suggested an OR :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796127/join-two-queries-where-both-query-having-two-tables-joined?noredirect=1#comment109304827_61796127):

> @Scratte yes absolutely i want result from the second query too

If you just want the 2 records from the first query and the one record from the second query, then you're not looking for a `JOIN`, but looking for `UNION`:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.country 
 from table1 t1
 join table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id a  
where t1.stats_code in ('100','200')
UNION
select t1.id, t1.name, null as country 
 from table t1
 join table t3 on t1.id = t3.id 
where t3.code in ('300')
```